# How to remove a portion of string in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please guide me on how to completely remove a particular portion from a string

Here is my string:

```
String greeting =Hello  #World# How Are You.
```

I want to remove the `#World#` portion. I tried the following but it does not work for me, and the reason is that the `##` portion is dynamic.

```
SELECT Replace(greeting, #World#, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @S varchar(50) = 'Hello  #World# How Are You.'

select stuff(@S,
             charindex('#', @S),
             charindex('#', @S, charindex('#', @S) + 1) - charindex('#', @S) + 1,
             '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
declare  @greeting nvarchar(max)
Set @greeting = 'Hello  #World# How Are You.'
Select replace(replace(@greeting,parsename(replace(replace(@greeting,'.','') ,'#','.'),2),''),'#','')
```

Result :-

```
Hello  How Are You.
```

The above solution will work fine if you have just one pattern like `#...#` in your `string`

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(50)
SET @Str = 'Hello  #World# How Are You.'

SELECT LEFT(@Str, CHARINDEX('#', @Str)-1)+
        RIGHT(@Str, CHARINDEX('#', REVERSE(@Str))-1)
```